# Rainbow HAT Android things temperature offset

Tags: java, iot, android-things

Whenever I run the "weatherstation" application from here: https://github.com/androidthings/weatherstation and let it run for a little while, the temperature sensing is off the charts.

My room is about 25C whereas the sensor starts of about 21C but rises to 41C!

Is there some offset I should know off?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the Pi Rainbow Hat, it has to do with the CPU heat interfering with the sensor.
https://github.com/pimoroni/rainbow-hat/issues/3

Maybe this post from the Google+ Android things developpers community can help you, though I haven't tested it myself.

https://plus.google.com/110363322293950405430/posts/RmHuhzE9Rsv